# Plone.app.Discussion : no notification for new entries when subscribing to new comments

Tags: plone

We seem to have a problem with plone.app.discussion 2.1.3 on Plone 4.1.4.

The first comment is tranferred without problems, the comment reviewer receives mails regarding the comment. However, if we check the box to enable notification of new comments on the document, subsequent comments only spark a message towards the reviewer and not the subscriber to the new comments.

We saw that there are some bug reports concerning plone.app.discussion but this does not really pertain to this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in plone.app.discussion. Please file a bug report in the plone.org issue tracker describing the exact steps to reproduce the problem:

https://dev.plone.org/newticket

Comment: sorry for finding a bug in your otherwise great product :-) . Filed the report under https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12863. If there is anything else I can be of use for, let me know...

Comment: There is absolutely no need to apologize! Reporting bugs is an important part of improving Plone. Thanks for reporting!